# Wrong letter spacing when using certain fonts

Tags: fonts, linux

I'm using [Classic Console](http://webdraft.hu/fonts/classic-console/) font in buffers. Unfortunately for some reason letter spacing is terrible in Emacs while being correct in Konsole and other programs.

Text in Emacs:
[image: Classic Console in Emacs]

Text in Konsole (using the same font and size):
[image: Classic Console in Konsole]

Any idea how to fix this?

**Another case with Courier Prime:**

[image]

```
'(default ((t (:family "Courier Prime" :foundry "QUQA" 
               :slant normal :weight normal :height 83 
               :width normal :spacing 10))))
```

`:spacing 10` did not work.

Comment: What exactly font used in Emacs? Type `C-u C-x =` on any character. Compare with `xlsfonts -fn '*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-m*'` or `fc-list :spacing=mono` like commands.

Comment: I have filling that in Konsole you use 13px font, but 12px in Emacs.

Comment: How are you setting the font?  Note the emacs sample use lots of different faces, some bold.  If these have different width to regular letters then you will see uneven spacing.

Comment: I had the same issue and fixed it for the font called "Hack". All it took was to set the font spacing. (set-default-font "Hack-11:spacing=110") or in your case: (set-default-font "Classic Console-11:spacing=100")

Comment: @PedroPenna, that didn't work for me; I've put `(set-default-font "Courier Prime:spacing=10")`

Comment: Setting spacing to 100 or 90 worked for me. See this question - its closely related: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/55096/2418

Answer (score 1):

10 is not a valid spacing, try: `90` dual or `100` mono.

Eg:

```el
'(default ((t (:family "Courier Prime" :foundry "QUQA" 
               :slant normal :weight normal :height 83 
               :width normal :spacing 90))))
```