# How to make fonts show anti-aliased on Linux/X11?

Tags: fonts, x11

With Linux/X11, certain font's show without anti-aliasing.

- `JetBrains Mono`
- `Cascadia Code`
- These two fonts show with anti-aliasing in other programs (st terminal for example).
- All other fonts show with anti-aliasing (Source Code Pro, Fira Code Medium, Courier Code, Monoid).
- This is the feature-set of emacs `XPM JPEG TIFF GIF PNG RSVG IMAGEMAGICK SOUND GPM DBUS GSETTINGS GLIB NOTIFY ACL GNUTLS LIBXML2 FREETYPE M17N_FLT LIBOTF XFT ZLIB TOOLKIT_SCROLL_BARS GTK3 X11 XDBE XIM MODULES THREADS LIBSYSTEMD LCMS2`

---

Any hints on how to resolve this?

This is X11 with `JetBrains Mono-13` font, I think this is related to Emacs, not `fontconfig`, since the `st` terminal displays the font properly.

[image: Emacs in X11 with JetBrains Mono-13 font]

This is `emacs -nw` running in `st` terminal.

[image]

Comment: Which build variant of Emacs is this? Specifically, are you using Cairo and Harfbuzz? (check `system-configuration-features` to find out).

Comment: In case this isn’t obvious, this isn’t what emacs is supposed to look like.

Comment: Updated with `system-configuration-features` and a screenshot of the same font in `st`.

Answer (score 3):

Found a solution, neither of these fonts define themselves as mono-spaced, 
the solution is to force this.

This can be done in `fonts.conf` or through the font specifier.

- `Cascadia Code-13:spacing=90` (dual spacing)
- `JetBrains Mono-13:spacing=100` (mono spacing)

---

Modifying the `fonts.conf` is meant to work too, although I couldn't get it working. [See link](https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-fonts/issues/1128).

Comment: You're using an XFT build. Lots of font-related things, especially with newer fonts like JetBrain Mono, tends to work a lot bettwe in a Cairo+Harfbuzz build.

Comment: From what I've read `Cairo` build is currently unstable (as of Emacs 26)