# Every letter in emacs is now separated by a space

Tags: fonts

Today when I opened Emacs (26.3) for the first time since updating Linux (Arch) I was greeted with a wide (two spaces) cursor, and every letter on the screen separated by a space, like this:

```
F i l e    l o c a t i o n s
```

This is true everywhere: in the text, in the mode line, in the linum numbers to the left on the window. The only place it isn't true is in a read-only buffer like the initial screen that comes up when you start Emacs. I don't see any errors in the *Messages* buffer.

I don't know where to start.  Any ideas?

Comment: Replacing the font Inconsolata with FiraCode (or for that matter, anything else) in Emacs solves the problem. No idea why.

Comment: I also ran into strange xft font handing issue that only impacted certain fonts, perhaps this answer helps: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/55096/2418

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an issue with how Xft calculates the width of characters, which is triggered by Inconsolata. See [Inconsolata](https://github.com/googlefonts/Inconsolata/issues/42) for full details.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to specify the XFT spacing explicitly.

The font may not be declared mono-spaced, 
the solution is to force this through the font specifier.

- `Fira Code-13:spacing=90` (dual spacing)
- `Fira Code-13:spacing=100` (mono spacing)