# Every monospace glyph rendered with two whitespaces after?

Tags: fonts

As said in the title, every monospace glyph seem to be "rendered" as itself plus two whipespace characters; so, for example, the cursor is three characters wide. This doesn't happen with any part of the interface which uses non monospace fonts.

I checked and this happens also with an empty configuration.

I'm on Arch Linux, which is shipping Emacs 26.3.

Comment: I have a feeling this is a duplicate, but I can't find it...

Comment: It is a [duplicate](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/57481/every-letter-in-emacs-is-now-separated-by-a-space).

Comment: As @FranBurstall said. Does this answer your question? [Every letter in emacs is now separated by a space](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/57481/every-letter-in-emacs-is-now-separated-by-a-space)

Comment: @FranBurstall: Thanks for finding it.