# Emacs font has extra spaces between letters

Tags: gui-emacs

I haven't used my emacs setup for a while and now when I open emacs it looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

The extra spacing between the letters does not disappear when I use `emacs -q` to load emacs without the config.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to fix this?

Comment: You can narrow it down by iteratively commenting out half of your init file, until only the lines causing the bug remain.

Comment: Which font are you using? You can check using `C-u C-x =`. My crystal ball says "Consolas".

Comment: Sorry, I meant "Inconsolata"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Every letter in emacs is now separated by a space](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/57481/every-letter-in-emacs-is-now-separated-by-a-space)

Comment: @rpluim Yes it is Inconsolata Regular. Is that the problem?

Comment: See the question linked by @wasamasa

Comment: I see I didn't do a proper job searching for the answer. Thank you @wasamasa.

Comment: @rpluim Thank you as well.